# How do I show the number of tables in all databases?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a query that return all the databases in my *MySQL* database (i.e. like `SHOW DATABASES;` but includes the number of tables in the tabular result.)

Something that outputs:

```
+--------------------+--------+
| Database           | Tables |
+--------------------+--------+
| information_schema |     40 |
| db1                |     97 |
| db2                |    135 |
```

etc.

Is there a simple query or command that can be typed from the *mysql* command line that produces that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the information_schema.tables

```
select table_schema, count(1)
from information_schema.tables
group by table_schema
```

Comment: This one works, but leaves out all empty databases (i.e. those with 0 tables).

Comment: You can do a left join between information_schema.SCHEMATA and tables if you want schemas without tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
USE DATEBASE;
SHOW TABLES;
```

or even better:

```
SHOW TABLES IN database
```

Comment: It gives me the count, but I have to repeat it for every *database*.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  table_schema,
  sum(table_type = 'base table') tables,
  sum(table_type = 'view') views,
  sum(table_type = 'system view') system_views
from information_schema.tables
group by table_schema;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/22726

Or just `count(1)` instead of those sums to count them all together.